# Spring Data, Hibernate 4.1.1 and Spring JTA Transaction Manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jta, spring-data

I am in the process of developing a web application and decided that using spring-data would be a good idea. To be fair it makes life extremely easy and the DAO layer very thin.

The issue I am have is to do with persisting data. When I use a JPATransactionManager the persistence works as expected. But I need to use a JTATransactionManager. When I use this it appears that the transaction looks fine but the hibernate flush does not seem to be associated with the tx commit

> DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Creating new transaction with name [com.clubgroups.user.registration.service.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.registerUser]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
>
> DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Participating in existing transaction
>
> DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Initiating transaction commit

Above is the debug message that confirms that the transaction is being committed. But the data does not seem to be flushed to the database.

I initialize the transaction manager like this:

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();       

    return transactionManager;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe you put a read-only flag somewhere? Or did you change FlushMode to MANUAL somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit puzzled about your JTA setup as it's highly unusual. First, have a look at [the reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#d0e20593) on how to setup JTA transactions correctly. Simply instantiating the `JtaTransactionManager` doesn't work as you need to obtain a `UserTransaction` from JNDI by some means. You should see an error popping up if you call `afterPropertiesSet()` in your `@Bean` method as this will unveil the missing configuration.